# How do you update a secret's value using CloudFormation without re-generating the password

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I am generating a new password inside of an AWS Secrets Manager secret using CloudFormation, however, when I change another part of the secret's JSON payload, the password is re-generated and changes. Is there a way to make CloudFormation leave a password as it was initially generated and not change it when the other JSON fields change?

```
new Secret(this, 'MySecret', {
  secretName: 'MySecret',
  description: 'Secret to access the database.',
  generateSecretString: {
    secretStringTemplate: '{ "user": "foo", server: "bar" }',
    generateStringKey: 'password'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, any change to the [GenerateSecretString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-secretsmanager-secret-generatesecretstring.html) structure will cause the password value to be regenerated. This is because various fields in that structure are rules about the value content (such as length, char set, etc) and we don't have a good way of knowing what the previous value was.

What is your use case for making manual changes to the JSON payload? This typically isn't something that you would need to do regularly.

Comment: Actually I agree, this shouldn't change. However, I have been setting up a secret for an existing DB which already had a username and password which I wanted to use. I used GenerateSecretString to generate a random password, then in the console, manually changed the password to the existing one. Issue was that if I renamed the secret or something in CDK the password was lost. I wonder if I were to explicitly set an empty password in the secret (without using GenerateSecretString) then manually change it, if that would keep the password the same if the secret's name etc... changed?

Comment: Are you working with RDS? If yes, I wonder if you can solve this with a secret target attachment, with `secret.addTargetAttachment()` (uses `AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment`). This way after CF deploys your secret it gets updated with the connection information, is this what you are looking for to change after the secret is deployed?

Comment: The secret name is a unique identifier. You cannot change it. Doing so in CFN, deletes the secret and creates a new one.

Comment: @jogold can you give me an code sample of how to use addtargetAttachment(). I want to add my new RDS db say 'X' to the secrets manager 'Y' . what are the correct parameters to be passed for this method.

Comment: @user3742114 in v1.19.0 you have an example here https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/5597bbe64446a07041f5469fc0897544448d4e95/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager/test/test.secret.ts#L313-L337, this is going to change in the next version https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/f10b3e64feab9c9ccc78c9820dc99a8b6b0971ec/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager/test/test.secret.ts#L312-L335